# How to use $slice and project specific fields together in MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

https://mongoplayground.net/p/U2vvNZHIbfq

I created the situation to the above link, you can simply hit the run button
Now I can set **slice** to 2, to make sure to project the first two item in "cars" only.

However, I don't know how to apply **projecting specific fields** only with "slice".

I want to project the "**name**" and "**views**" in the "cars" array only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another project to hide unused fields,

```
  // you pipeline stages
  {
    $project: {
      "cars._id": 0,
      "cars.categoryId": 0,
      "cars.description": 0
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/a7mCfgmTLrP)

---

Second way using `$map` in same stage,

- `$map` to iterate loop of array that slice from `cars` array, return `name` and `views` fields

```
  // you pipeline stages
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      categoryName: 1,
      cars: {
        $map: {
          input: { $slice: ["$cars", 2] },
          in: {
            name: "$$this.name",
            views: "$$this.views"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c5tLLEqBB3g)

Comment: Thanks, it works. One more question: How to sort by views in "cars"? https://mongoplayground.net/p/vV65jQXl26G   it doesn't work with $sort

Comment: for sort you need to do $unwind, cars and $sort and then $group. or other option if this works for you i am not sure. [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BLVWvcHhms_) this will sort only in ascending order by first field of the array object,.